# Problem with binding Telerik's RADTreeView Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I have followed this simple example and implemented similarly:-

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/tree_databindinghierarchical.html

The problem:-
GetDataSet() method returns a DataSet with the complete Ques table with all the rows and columns(QuesID,QuesParentID,QuesAns,Active,QuesTypeID and so on)

Now the probelm is that the RadTreeview is not binding well. Like The root node displays Questions but the the child nodes are not displaying the correspoding answer.
Also, some root nodes do not have a child node at all. Those root nodes that DO have a child node are displaying Questions as their text and not Answers.
I surmise it's something wrong with the BindTree() method only. What could it be? I mean RADTreeView is implemented in a very simple manner in that link above. I only followed accordingly.
What is wrong??

aspx page;-

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

<telerik:RadTreeView runat="server" ID="tree1" OnNodeDataBound="tree1_NodeDataBound"></telerik:RadTreeView>

</asp:Content>
```

[EDIT]

In the Ques table, some records under the column QuesParentID are NULL.Is it something to do with this column????

Is this the correct way to assign values to attributes like I have in the BindTree method??

```
 tree1.DataTextField = "Ques";
        tree1.DataValueField = "QuesAns";
        tree1.DataFieldID = "QuesID";
        tree1.DataFieldParentID = "QuesParentID";
```

Comment: Has anyone worked with Telerik's RADTreeView Control here? Need help plz.

Comment: Serenity,

were you able to figure out the solution. I have the same issue!!